# InnoSetup pascal inheriting TControl causes identifier expected

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to create my own InnoSetup Control (combined dropdown and file input box with browse button). I need dynamic number of these controls. My idea was to inherit TControl and build the needed control like that.

```
type
  TConfigControl = class(TControl)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  end;
```

I am not avid Pascal programmer but I think the syntax should be correct. When I try to compile the InnoSetup script it gives "Identifier expected" to the second line.

On the other hand, is this the correct way to do this kind of thing in innosetup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your component in Delphi - regular Pascal allows you to do this.

Inno Setup Script cannot handle such situations (it is pretty complicated).

So develop plug-in (.dll file) and use it to place your control on Wizard's form.

Comment: How this is different from my (finally deleted) answer ? In the suggestion to make an external library (or COM object, if we are at) ? And, *"You can create your component in Delphi - regular Pascal allows you to do this"* makes no sense to me. You wanted to suggest OP to build their own InnoSetup or what is the thought ?

Comment: The 'Pascal' language used in Inno Setup is not the same as in Delphi IDE. It is a 'light' version of Pascal and it does not allows you to do such complicated stuff.

Comment: No, it is the Pascal Script; scripting language similar to Pascal.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is a reason why I wrote 'Pascal'.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that ' :-)